# how to insert a picture using clear javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Schematically what I want. How to do it?

```
<img src=incamingMessage>
<script>
  var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9090/");

  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var incomingMessage = event.data;
    insertPic(incomingMessage);
  };

  function insertPic(message) {
    //here something that change <img>
  };

  //event.data = "img/312.png"
</script>
```

update added listener. i dont know how to change arg in img

Comment: You've to create a [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onmessage) for the WebSocket messages. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: @Teemu i have been updated

Comment: You can't use JS variables in the markup like that. Instead, change `src` property of the image in the message handler. (Ex. give `id` to the image in the markup, then get a reference to the image element and change its `src`.)

Comment: @Teemu in general it was a topic question. can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Didn't I just _explain_ it in the comment above? [Document manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) is one of the fundamentals of how JS works with HTML ...

Answer (score 0):

At first, who is `event.data`?
What data type? What kind of variable? Where is it defined? Is it an array of bytes? is it a `var`?

What you do is probably better doable with PHP like this:

```
<?php

$incomingMessage = // populate with the actual data from your source.

echo '<img src="'.incomingMessage'">';

?>
```

As for Javascript, I have no idea what to tell you because you did not provide any info about the source of the data, the variable that stores it, etc.

Comment: sorry, i have been updated post, event.data is message from websocket. so if I understand correctly php is superfluous

Comment: In this case, yes, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById(id).src = incomingMessage;
that what i wanted to know